# Facebook SDK 4.0 app invite android

Tags: android, facebook-sdk-4.0

I was using below code for app invitation.

```
if (AppInviteDialog.canShow()) {
AppInviteContent content = new AppInviteContent.Builder()
            .setApplinkUrl(appLinkUrl)
            .setPreviewImageUrl(previewImageUrl)
            .build();
AppInviteDialog.show(this, content);
}
```

every time i run code i got nothing.
no error or no warning nothing

I followed [App invite](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-invites/android) link but get no result after facebook login screen.
Any idea what wrong with this?

Comment: Jigar may you please elaborate this issue... How you created Applink and how exactly the setup was created ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `appLinkUrl` must be [AppLink](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/applinks) url, not just link to your app. (Yeah, it is confusing, but I have faced with this on my own experience). If you dont have one, you can create it [here](https://developers.facebook.com/quickstarts/?platform=app-links-host).

Comment: @VadymVL Is it compulsory to have `Facebook app` to make `App Invite` work?